# Dropbox API on iPhone: How to download and access the data

Tags: iphone, dropbox, dropbox-api, nsdocumentdirectory

I am downloading files from Dropbox into the user's Documents folder using this:

```
[[self restClient] loadFile:filepath intoPath:[self getDocumentPath]];

    -(NSString *)getDocumentPath {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *filepath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"filepathDropbox"];
        NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filepath];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:path forKey:@"filepathDropbox"];
        return path;
    }
```

Once this is completed, how do I access this file on the local iphone?

Comment: Whats wrong here? You are doing right. Saving file to Documents directory correctly. 
Could you please explain why do you use this line?
`NSString *filepath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"filepathDropbox"];`

Comment: i am saving the filepath so that I can retrieve the location of what i saved in another xib. I am able to save the file to the Documents directory, but how do i retrieve the data?

Comment: retrieve data as you retrieve from document directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self getDocumentPath]];
```

?